# How to add Purchased From(store) in programmatically order

Tags: magento-1.8, product, orders, controllers, backend

I have a script to create order programmatically in magento 1.

Everything works fine except the fact that my created order doesn't have this field (Purchased From(store)) like in the picture bellow

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
    foreach($product as $key => $value){
        $sku_qty = implode(" ",$value);
        $sqk_qty_array = explode(";",$sku_qty);
        $sku = ($sqk_qty_array[1]);
        $sku_array = explode(".", $sku);
        $products[] = $sku_array[0]."-".$sku_array[0].".".$sku_array[1]."-".$sku_array[2]." ".$sqk_qty_array[2];    
    }
    //take products id by sku
    $products_id = array();
    foreach($products as $key=> $value){
         //take the sku from array without qty
        $sku_no_qty = explode(" ",$value);
        $sku = $sku_no_qty[0];
        $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku($sku);
        $product_id_qty[] = $id."-".$sku_no_qty[1];
        $products_id []=$id;
    }

    //add order by script
    $email = "test@yahoo.com";
    $productids = $products_id;
    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    // Start New Sales Order Quote
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());
    //products count
    $prod_num = count($products_id);
    // Set Sales Order Quote Currency
    $quote->setCurrency($order->AdjustmentAmount->currencyID);
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->loadByEmail($email);
    if ($customer->getId() == "") {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                ->setStore($store)
                ->setFirstname('Client')
                ->setLastname('Jolidon')
                ->setEmail($email)
                ->setPassword("password");
        $customer->save();
    }

    // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
    // Configure Notification
    $quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
    foreach ($product_id_qty as  $id)
    {   $split = explode("-", $id);
        $id=$split[0]; 
        $qty =$split[1];
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
        $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $qty)));
    }

    // Set Sales Order Billing Address
    $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
        'customer_address_id' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
        'firstname' => 'Client',
        'middlename' => 'Client',
        'lastname' => 'Client',
        'suffix' => '',
        'company' => '',
        'street' => array(
            '0' => '',
            '1' => 'Client64'
        ),
        'city' => 'Client',
        'country_id' => 'Client',
        'region' => 'Client',
        'postcode' => 'Client',
        'telephone' => 'Client',
        'fax' => 'Client',
        'vat_id' => '',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
            ));

    // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
        'customer_address_id' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
        'firstname' => 'Client',
        'middlename' => 'Unic',
        'lastname' => 'Client',
        'suffix' => '',
        'company' => '',
        'street' => array(
            '0' => 'Client',
            '1' => '45'
        ),
        'city' => 'Client',
        'country_id' => 'Client',
        'region' => 'Client',
        'postcode' => 'Client',
        'telephone' => 'Client',
        'fax' => 'Client',
        'vat_id' => '',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
            ));
    if ($shipprice == 0) {
        $shipmethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
    }

    // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
            ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

    // Set Sales Order Payment
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

    // Collect Totals & Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    try {
        // Create Order From Quote
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service->submitAll();
        $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    // Resource Clean-Up
    $quote = $customer = $service = null;

    // Finished
    return  $this->_redirectUrl
```

How can i add this missing filed in my order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Setting Current Store

```
// Start New Sales Order Quote
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(1);
```